# Prove that T3SAT is NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, 3-sat

Instance: A boolean formula f(x1, . . . , xn) in 3CNF form, with m clauses labelled C1, . . . , Cm.

Is there an assignment to x1, . . . , xn such that every third clause is False and all other clauses are True? That is, Ci is False for all i ≡ 0 (mod 3), and Ci is True for all i ≡ 1 or 2 (mod 3).

how do I prove that this is NP-Complete?

I do know the fact, that there is a way to reduce this problem to 3SAT but I couldn't prove it just by adding an extra variable, to the set of clauses. Is there any better way to go about this?

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're also not looking for demands for us to do something for you.  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate some specific question about the situation you are facing.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

Consider $C_i=x_1\vee x_2\vee x_3$, $i\equiv 0\pmod 3$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ do not show up in other clauses. Then the problem becomes the normal 3SAT problem.